# Javascript - How to execute the executable file located in C:\?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webkit, exe, node-webkit

With NW i have following code. Which is executing Java or other scripts. But not able to run any location path for example the following is failing.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
function voidrun(input){
  run_void = exec(input, function (error, stdout, stderr) { 
    sys.print('stdout: ' + stdout); 
    sys.print('stderr: ' + stderr); 
    if (error !== null) { 
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
  }); 

  run_void.on('exit', function(code) {
      console.log('Child process exited '+ code);
  });  
}

function boot() {
    runme('C:\\run\splashscreen.exe');  
}
```

Comment: For starters, backslashes in JS strings have to be to be doubled like: `'C:\\\\run\\splashscreen.exe'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var cmd = 'executable.exe parameter1 parameter2';
var path = 'c:\\path';
var child = exec(
    cmd, {
        cwd: path
    },
    function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (error === null) {
            console.log('success');
        } else {
            console.log('error');
        }
    }
);
```